Allow child element to render outside of parent's bounds while still respecting parent's scroll

I have a child element in a scrollable parent.
I want the child to move as the parent is scrolled. I can do this if I position the child relative to the parent.
But I also want the child to show even if it's outside the parent's bounds. I can do this if I position the child relative to a grandparent.
How can I do both at the same time?


    #grandparent {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        outline: 5px red solid;
        padding: 10px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #parent {
        outline: 2px solid blue;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        position: relative;
    }

    #popup-target {
        outline: 1px solid orange
    }

    #popup-target:not(:hover) ~ #popup {
        display: none;
    }

    #popup {
        position: fixed;
        outline: 1px solid gold;
        background-color: lightgray;
        width: 100px;
    }
<div id="grandparent">
    <div id="parent">
        <div>text</div>
        <div>text</div>
        <div>text</div>
        <div>text</div>
        <div>text</div>
        <div>text</div>
        <div>text</div>
        <div id="popup-target">hover me</div>
        <div id="popup">
            <div>popup</div>
            <div>popup</div>
            <div>popup</div>
            <div>popup</div>
            <div>popup</div>
            <div>popup</div>
        </div>
        <div>text</div>
        <div>text</div>
        <div>text</div>
        <div>text</div>
        <div>text</div>
        <div>text</div>
        <div>text</div>
        <div>text</div>
        <div>text</div>
    </div>
</div>




Is the pop-up always going to be in the same place or just to the right of the target?

#popup will always below the #popup-target.  And there'll always be text above and below it.

Then we need to see what this is supposed to look like.

Added an image to the post
